# What is the serialization format of the Qt type QColor?

Tags: qt, serialization

I am not developing a Qt application but I am consuming an API exposed by one. I do not control that application.

I need to pass that application a byte array representing a QColor instance via a socket.

What is the serialization format of a QColor object? i.e. what bytes should I pass in to represent, for example, red? I am trying to find out without building a Qt application of my own that instantiates one and serializes it.

Comment: You state `"I do not control that application."` with regard to the sending application.  Do you have access to its source code? That is, do you know how it serializes the `QColor`?  Via a [`QDataStream`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#operator-lt-lt-1)?

Comment: It can be just `0xFF0000FF` for red. I normally use `QColor{QRgb{0xFF0000}};` to convert `uint` to `QColor`. The final `FF` is optional since it is the default value.